# Some standard improper integrals

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis, improper-integrals

Referring to part (b):

I don't know what $a$ stands for, and also don't get what "convergence" the author is referring to here. If he means the convergence as $a$ tends to $\infty$, then shouldn't the convergence instead be identical to that in part (a)?

[image]

Comment: $a$ is (presumably) a real, positive,  number. The difference between $(a)$ and $(b)$ is the lower limit of the integral. What happens if you look at the graph of $x^p$ at $x=0$ for $p\leq -1$?

Comment: @NigelOvermars Thanks. So does the author mean the convergence as $a$ tends to infinity? Why doesn't he just directly put ∞ in the domain of integration, like he did for part (a)?

Comment: It could be to $\infty$, but it is not necessary. For instance, does the integral $\int_0^1 x^{-1}dx$ diverge?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, $a$ is simply intended to be some fixed positive number.

The first two are closely related, as it turns out. Consider the following formal integrals: $$\int_a^\infty x^p\,dx\tag{$\heartsuit$}$$ $$\int_0^b x^p\,dx\tag{$\spadesuit$}$$

It is easy to see that $(\heartsuit)$ diverges when $p\ge 0,$ regardless of which real $a$ is chosen, since $x^p$ will then be (eventually) positive non-decreasing. On the other hand, $(\spadesuit)$ converges when $p\ge 0$ for any real $b,$ as an integral of a bounded continuous function. More interesting is what happens when we are dealing with $p<0.$

Let's suppose that $p<0,$ and that $a,b>0.$ Think about this in terms of the differential "area slices" under the curve.

When $p\ge-1,$ the vertical "area slices" don't get short enough quickly enough as we move to the right for $(\heartsuit)$ to converge.  If we were finding the area under the curve with an integral with respect to $dy,$ the horizontal "area slices" grow too long too quickly as we move down. Otherwise, we're fine.

When $p\le-1,$ the vertical "area slices" grow too tall too quickly as we move left toward the $y$-axis for $(\spadesuit)$ to converge. If we were finding the area under the curve with an integral with respect to $dy,$ the horizontal "area slices" don't get narrow enough quickly enough as we move up. Otherwise, we're fine.

Do you see how these behaviors are basically exact mirrors of each other?

Comment: I find it strange that many calculus texts covering improper integrals do not mention the convergence condition for the Type II integral [formula (b) above, your (♠)] -- it really is straightforward enough to derive and understand...

Answer (score 2):

Note that the lower limit of two integral (a)(b) is different. This is a big difference.

(b) is 
$$\int_0^a x^pdx=[\frac{1}{p+1}x^{p+1}]_0^a=\frac{a^{p+1}}{p+1}$$
if $p\not =-1.$

What do you think?